# how to know the number of times that an instance has been created?

Tags: java

I want to prevent instances from been created over the limit, the following code is the best practices?

```
public class Foo {
    private static volatile int count = 0;

    {
        synchronized (Foo.class) {
            count++;
            if (count > 10) {
                throw new RuntimeException("the instance cannot be created for more than 10 times.");
            }
        }
    }

    public Foo() { ... }
    public Foo(String arg) { ... }
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if there are any ways to bypass the check.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you really want to achieve. Do you want to avoid having more then 10 instances created at all or in parallel? Anyway, throwing RuntimeException during construction is not a good practice. I would rather go for private constructors and a Factory method. If you need assist on that, let me know

Comment: And using `RuntimeException` like that in any circumstances is not good practice.  Either use an existing more specific exception class ... or declare one for yourself.

Comment: Pls ingore the `RuntimeException` here, it may be something other...

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: What happens when an instance goes out of scope and/or is garbage collected?  Do you want only 10 instances created for the life of the application, or a limit of 10 instances at any one time?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? Are you trying to guard against coding mistakes ("oops, I created too many objects!") or something like a malicious attack? Right off the bat, one thing that jumps out with your `static count` approach is that it'll make it harder to unit test: either tests will have to reuse objects (which makes them more fragile) or you'll have to figure out a backdoor that lets you get around the 10-instance restriction. (Or you'll be limited to a max of ~10 tests.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. If you want to limit the instantiation of your class, I would rather prefer a factory method. Setting the class to final should also prevent overwriting it...

```
package abc;

public final class Foo {

    private static final Object o = new Object();

    private static volatile int count = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) throws InstantiationException {
        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
            final Foo foo = Foo.newInstance("HelloWorld!-" + i);
            System.out.println(foo.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Foo newInstance(final String message) throws InstantiationException {
        synchronized (o) {
            count++;
            if (count > 10) {
                throw new InstantiationException("the instance cannot be created for more than 10 times.");
            }
            return new Foo(message);
        }
    }

    private final String message;

    private Foo(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

But once more is this really what you want to do? Or do you want to reduce the number of parallel instances?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: It'll bypass with reflection.

Comment: If the external code you're worried about has permissions to access private members via reflection, there's not much you can do. In the snippet in your question, for example, someone could also just use reflection to set `count = 0` (or even set it to 15 before you instantiate any objects, as a denial of service).

Comment: As yshavit already mentioned, there is not much you can do against reflection, if you do not limit it via the security manager. Some could also decompile your class files, change the code and use 'customized' classes

Comment: ↑ Thank you to tell me the `security manager` has capability to limit reflection.

Comment: Oh, also: you should check `count` _before_ you increment it, not after. As written, this code (and the code in the question itself) has a vulnerability: if you invoke it enough times to cause integer overflow, you'll be able to create more objects. I haven't tried it (don't have Java on my current machine), but I doubt it would take very long.

Comment: Use of Java modules will also protect against reflective access, as long as you control the startup of Java.